Flink 1.16 metrics with OpenTelemetry
Requirement - Want to implement OpenTelemetry metrics to the flink java application
Flink version - 1.16

added the below dependancy to my fink java application POM

   <dependency>
   <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
   <artifactId>opentelemetry-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.30.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
   <artifactId>opentelemetry-sdk</artifactId>
   <version>1.30.0</version>
</dependency>


Implement below OTEL metrics to my flink application

import io.opentelemetry.api.GlobalOpenTelemetry;
import io.opentelemetry.api.metrics.DoubleHistogram;
import io.opentelemetry.api.metrics.Meter;


public class OTELMetrics {

private DoublrHidyohtsm historgram;


Meter meter = GlobalOpenTelemetry.meterBuilfer(OTELMetrics.class.toString()).build();
historgram = meter.histogramBuilder("MY_Custom_Metrics").setUnit("ms").build();


----------
-------------


Attributes attr = Attributes.builder().put("Param1", val1).put("param2", valu2);
historgram.record(startTime, attr );


}



Build and deployed the flink application, but metrics are not visible into the flink dashboard metrics.

Couple of Questions

Is Flink 1.16 supports OpenTelemetry?
if it supports why the metrics are not showing in the flink dashboard?
can you pleas share some working code for flink with OpenTelemetry implementation.


check out https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-examples
